# My java program is showing runtime error while submitting it on uva.onlinejudge.org

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am trying to solve a uva problem **"Greedy Gift Givers"** (problem number 119, Link: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=55 ). I am using java to solve that problem and my code works fine while running it on my computer, but the problem is when I submit it to uva online judge it shows me **RUNTIME ERROR**. I did not get where the problem is. I also have less idea about **RUNTIME ERROR**. My code is given below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        String name[];
        int cost[];
        while (inp.hasNextLine()) {
            n = inp.nextInt();
            name = new String[n];
            cost = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                name[i] = inp.next();
            }

            for (int p = 0; p < n; p++) {
                String temp_name = inp.next();
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if (temp_name.equals(name[i])) {
                        int gift = inp.nextInt(), num = inp.nextInt();
                        if (num != 0 && gift >= 0) {
                            cost[i] -= (int) (gift / num) * (int) num;
                        }
                        for (int k = 0; k < num; k++) {
                            String temp_name_2 = inp.next();
                            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                                if (temp_name_2.equals(name[j])) {
                                    if (num != 0 && gift >= 0) {
                                        cost[j] += gift / num;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.println(name[i] + " " + cost[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the class must not be public

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that you use `System.in` while the online judge gives a file to the input of your program. The last string og the input section:

> The input consists of one or more groups and is terminated by end-of-**file**.

Comment: Thank You for answering, but I couldn't understand your answer, can you please explain it more, and show me where should I change my code.

Comment: You have `Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);`. So you expect input data from `System.in`. And the testing system gives a a name of the file to your program. I haven't found the rules for reading input in your link. Try to find it and read the input something like: `new Scanner(new File("name_of_the_input_file"))`